# C# Spintax Coloring

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, spinning, spintax

Spintax is used for getting multiple pieces of content from one piece ex:
Spintax: The {dog|cat} {ran|jumped} very {quietly|far {ahead|away}}.
That would return sentences like these:
The dog ran very quietly.
The cat jumped very quietly. 
The dog jumped very far ahead.
The cat ran very far away.

I figured out how to turn the spintax into random different sentences but I now want to display the spintax with coloring (in a rich text box).  What I mean by that is everything between the {} and the {} themselves would be a different color(blue).  When there are {} inside other {} it would be another color(green).  When generating sentences I started from the deepest brackets (the {} that did not have any other {} inside them).  I think that for the coloring I have to start from the outside but I don't know how.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var input = "hello {one {two}} there";
var depth = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
{
    if (input[index]==('{'))
        depth++;
    else if (input[index]==('}'))
        depth--;

    // depending on your depth, use whatever color you want
    // maybe have an array of colors "color_array", and just
    // use color_array[depth] to get your color
}
```

You'll have to have a look at your end cases and how you deal with the `{` and `}` colorwise, but you should be able to go on from here.

Comment: Not sure why you say it has to start with black ... (unless you mean if you want the "default" color (depth = 0) to be black ... yep ... :)